# How to display blog images using wordpress in existing project

Tags: php, html

I have developed a website using html and php. To display blog details i have used wordpress. But im able to display only the content without any Image. Plz guide me how to write code to display the blog images in the front page.

```
code used to display recent blog details which is in index.php
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>




    <!-- Blog Section-->
<section id="blog"> 
<?php

$number_of_posts = 3;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => $number_of_posts );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent_post ){
echo "<span>".$recent_post['post_date']."</span> <br>";
echo "<h3>".$recent_post['post_title']."</h3>";


echo  "<p>".$recent_post['post_content']."</p><br><br>";

}

?>
</section>
```

and output is

[image: blog details]

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: DON'T DO IT! Even if yesterday you said tomorrow!

Including WordPress's core in some other files is the last thing you want to do. Instead, use an Ajax method and fill the content by using a REST endpoint.

You need to register a rest route first. To do so, add this piece of code into your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'vinay', '/ajax_blog/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET', 
            'callback' => 'blog_ajax_function' 
    ) );
});
// Now, you can do your query inside a callback function:
function blog_ajax_function(){
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, OBJECT );
    foreach ( $recent_posts as $post=>$value ) {
        $data[$post]['title'] = get_the_title( $value->ID );
        $data[$post]['date'] = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $value->ID );
        $data[$post]['permalink'] = get_the_permalink( $value->ID );
        $data[$post]['thumbnail'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $value->ID );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Now, you can get a JSON response containing title, date and thumbnail of your recent posts by visiting `wp-json/vinay/ajax_blog/`. Time to add them to our page.

Let's bind an action to page load and fill the page with fancy bubbly posts, just like spongebob did! This goes in your static website's HTML file ( Replace the code from your question by removing it and using  this ) Don't forget to change `example.com` to your domain!

```
<section id="blog"><div id="container-div"></div></section>
<script>
(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'http://example.com/wp-json/vinay/ajax_blog', 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    $('#container-div').append('<a href="'+element.permalink+'"><img src="'+element.thumbnail+'" alt="'+element.title+'"/><span>'+element.title+'</span>' +element.date+ '</a>');
                });
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This will automatically append a list of clickable recent posts to the `<div id="container-div"></div>` that we create in our HTMl to contain the posts when the page loads.

All done.

Comment: This is a better way.

Comment: Thank u sir... a small doubt.. callback function-> where i need to add.. and should i create wp-json folder containing vinay and ajax-blog folders?????????? and where i have to add last code.. Plz i need full details where to add the code..

Comment: You're welcome! All the PHP goes in your WordPress theme's functions.php file, and the JavaScript goes in the bottom of your HTML template (not WordPress).

Comment: Thank u sir,, but one more query............. i have to remove my code or with that code i hve to add the script?????????????? and do i need to make changes in the script like url and others.......... as im new to jquery plz help me to make changes....

Comment: 1) After adding the code to your theme's `functions.php`, try to access `http://example.com/wp-json/vinay/ajax-blog`. if you see the result in text without errors, then it's good. 2) remove the code in your HTML file and _only_ add this `<section id="blog"><div id="container-div"></div></section>` to it (also the jQuery script I wrote). The jQuery script will automatically fetch your posts from WordPress and add it to the `<div id="container-div"></div>`. don't forget to change `example.com` to your domain :)

Comment: I've also updated the answer for you. Make sure you have jQuery loaded though :) @vinay

Comment: functions.php is in blog/wp-content/themes/superior/functions.php............ so do i need to make changes in this path or i have to create a new functions.php in wp-json folder???

Comment: Yes, you should do it in `blog/wp-content/themes/superior/functions.php`. You should never modify any file outside `wp-content` (except `wp-config.php` in some situations)

Comment: Enjoy it :) and let me know if you had any more problem.

Comment: When Im trying to access->http://example.com/wp-json/vinay/ajax-blog........................ im getting 404 error Not Found

The requested document was not found on this server.

Comment: I assume you have changed the example with your domain. Also, you need to change the permalink structure from `Settings > Permalink` to anything _other_ than plain.

Comment: yes sir i hve changed example to my domainname... if i change permalink,, then url of my existing website will be changed??

Comment: Yes they will. But if you don't want to change them, you can use this instead: `https://example.com/?rest_route=/vinay/ajax-blog`. Does the same when you have plain permalinks.

Comment: I have changed permalink,, but still im nt able to display anything. https://example.com/?rest_route=/vinay/ajax-blog this link also not showing any blog posts